# How can I get the icon from the executable file only having an instance of it's Process in C#

Tags: c#

I can get the executable location from the process, how do I get the icon from file?

Maybe use windows api LoadIcon(). I wonder if there is .NET way...

Comment: See also, almost a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873356/where-is-a-net-application-icon-stored

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
Icon ico = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(theProcess.MainModule.FileName);
```

Comment: `Process.MainModule` can throw `Win32Exception`s on system processes or between 32-bit and 64-bit processes.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501771/how-to-avoid-a-win32-exception-when-accessing-process-mainmodule-filename-in-c) for details.

Comment: Also, my icons have no transparency giving ugly black outlines :/

Answer (score 13):

This is a sample from a console application implementation.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;         //For Icon
using System.Reflection;      //For Assembly

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                //Gets the icon associated with the currently executing assembly
                //(or pass a different file path and name for a different executable)
                Icon appIcon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);                
            }
            catch(ArgumentException ae) 
            {
                //handle
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Correction, that code does it for the current assembly...  not related.  oh, and you're missing parens.

Comment: Instead of using reflection for current assembly, wouldn't it be faster to use `Icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);`?

Answer (score 3):

Use the [ExtractIconEx](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32/ExtractIconEx.html) (and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648069.aspx)) p/invoke. You can extract small and large icons from any dll or exe. Shell32.dll itself has over 200 icons that are quite useful for a standard Windows application. You just have to first figure out what the index is for the icon(s) you want.

Edit: I did quick SO search and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189031/set-same-icon-for-all-my-forms#189618). The index 0 icon is the application icon.