# How can i add to listBox1 all the processes names and also each process icon near it like in task manager?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
            foreach (Process theprocess in processlist)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(theprocess.ProcessName);
                icons.Add(Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(theprocess.MainModule.FileName));
            }
```

This way i'm adding all processes to the listBox1.

But i'm getting exception access denied (I'm under admin rights i ran the visual studio as admin) on the line:

```
icons.Add(Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(theprocess.MainModule.FileName));
```

Win32Exception: Access is denied

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467259
  Message=Access is denied
  Source=System
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
  NativeErrorCode=5
  StackTrace:
       at System.Diagnostics.ProcessManager.OpenProcess(Int32 processId, Int32 access, Boolean throwIfExited)
       at System.Diagnostics.NtProcessManager.GetModuleInfos(Int32 processId, Boolean firstModuleOnly)
       at System.Diagnostics.NtProcessManager.GetFirstModuleInfo(Int32 processId)
       at System.Diagnostics.Process.get_MainModule()
       at HardwareMonitoring.Form1..ctor() in d:\C-Sharp\HardwareMonitoring\HardwareMonitoring\Hardwaremonitoring\Form1.cs:line 124
       at HardwareMonitoring.Program.Main() in d:\C-Sharp\HardwareMonitoring\HardwareMonitoring\Hardwaremonitoring\Program.cs:line 17
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

What i want to do is to list in the listBox1 all the processes and near each process on it's right side to display also it's logo. Just like it show in the windows task manager. How can i do it ?

Comment: Do you know th name of the process that throws this exception ? This is clearly a permission issue. Also, did you try running it outside of Visual Studio ?

Comment: karim yes it stop on csrss. Before it was stop on task manager but i closed the task manager. Now it stop  on csrss. I used try and catch to find the process/app it stop on. What should i do ? Should i ignore those apps or i should solve it so i can get any app icon ?

Comment: Also tried to run it out of the visual studio same exception.

Comment: And i see now when im running task manager i see also the task manager icon there and when im running the task manager it dosent prompt for admin (YES/NO) . So i wonder how the task manager is working and what apps it does get the icons of.

Comment: csrss does not have an icon.. which you can see because the `default icon for apps that do not have an icon` is shown in task manager.

Answer (score 2):

Your code should work - unless **a)** there is no `Icon` associated as Dan-o said **or b)** you try to acces a 64-bit process from a 32-bit process. Simply putting a `try` around the offending line and `catching` with a default `Icon` solves the issues.

So, this is more or less what you've got, with the `catch` clause and also a custom class for use with the `ListBox`:

```
// a class to work with the listbox:
class proc
{
    public Process process { get; set; }
    public proc (Process process_) {process = process_;}
    public override string ToString() { return process.MainWindowTitle; }
}


// a button-click to fill/refresh the list:
private void cb_refresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lb_processes.Items.Clear();

    var allProcceses = Process.GetProcesses();
    foreach (Process process in allProcceses)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(process.MainWindowTitle))
            lb_processes.Items.Add(new proc(process));
    }
}


// the event to display the icon:
private void lb_processes_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process p = ((proc)lb_processes.SelectedItem).process;
    // the process list is cached -> refresh & leave if a process has ended!  
    if (p.HasExited)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("This process has exited!", p.MainWindowTitle);
        cb_refresh_Click(null, null);
        return;
    }

    try
    {
        pb_icon.Image = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(p.MainModule.FileName).ToBitmap(); 
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    { 
      // expected errors if there is no icon or the process is 64-bit
      if (ex is ArgumentException || ex is Win32Exception )
      {
        pb_icon.Image = pb_icon.Image = Bitmap.FromHicon(SystemIcons.Application.Handle); 
      }
      else
      {
        pb_icon.Image = pb_icon.Image = Bitmap.FromHicon(SystemIcons.Error.Handle); 
        throw;
      }
    }
```

**Edit**: Added improved error checking, as suggested.
    }

Comment: Yeah, but since you know the wherefore and why it isn't __that__ general. But, of course, it would be a good idea to also check the validity of the cached process.

Comment: isn't capturing ArgumentException and Win32Exception  enough?

Comment: Right, thanks for the pointer! I edited the answer. With [PInvoke](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/IsWow64Process.html) one __might__ be able to check the 32-64 bit issue, but I'd rather not do it myself..