# Why the discrepancy in number of Processes?

Tags: c#, vb.net, process

I'm trying to list ALL processes in a DataGridView.

When I Dim those first 2 lines and read the total processes count, it can be a number like 191 total processes. However, the loop that adds each process ends up with a number usually around half of the total number? I thought maybe there might be some sort of hidden logic where duplicates weren't being added, but some duplicates DO get added to the list once it's all done.

Can anyone point out the reason ALL of the processes aren't being added to the list?

Here's the code:

```
   Dim intProcessesCount As Integer = Process.GetProcesses.Count

   Dim localAll As Process() = Process.GetProcesses()

    Try

        For Each OneProcess As Process In localAll

            ' Extract the program's icon
            Dim ico As Icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(OneProcess.MainModule.FileName)
            Dim pID = OneProcess.Id.ToString

            imgID = pID

            ImageList1.Images.Add(pID, ico)

            Dim row As String() = New String() { _
                OneProcess.ProcessName, _
                OneProcess.MainModule.FileVersionInfo.FileName}

            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)

        Next

    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.Print("Error: " & ex.Message)
    End Try

    ttslStats.Text = "Total Processes: " & DataGridView1.Rows.Count
```

Comment: Note that there is a way your code can skip adding a row for each process. Check you `Debug.Print` output.

Comment: I get this in the Output window, but only once: `A first chance exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in System.dll
Error: Access is denied`

It happens whether I run the IDE as admin or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That exception that you see in the output window breaks your `for` loop because the `try/catch` encloses the whole `for` loop. So, you only get processes which appear in the `localAll` *before* the one that causes the exception.

If you move the `try/catch` inside the loop it would keep going through the `localAll` so you should get the original number minus the number of exceptions:

```
    For Each OneProcess As Process In localAll

      Try
        ' Extract the program's icon
        Dim ico As Icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(OneProcess.MainModule.FileName)
        Dim pID = OneProcess.Id.ToString

        imgID = pID

        ImageList1.Images.Add(pID, ico)

        Dim row As String() = New String() { _
            OneProcess.ProcessName, _
            OneProcess.MainModule.FileVersionInfo.FileName}

        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)

     Catch ex As Exception
       Debug.Print("Error: " & ex.Message)
     End Try
    Next
```

Also, you're getting a new list of processes each time you call `GetProcesses()` so the second call may return a different number of processes if any new processes were started or some existing ones have exited between the two calls.

You should call `GetProcesses()` once, assign the result to `localAll` right away and then use that to get the count:

```
Dim localAll As Process() = Process.GetProcesses()

Dim intProcessesCount As Integer = localAll.Count
```

Comment: Ahhhh. It's always something "simple" that ya overlook, lol. Now that I've done that it coughs up about 8 more of those exceptions, plus a couple of these: `A first chance exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in System.dll
Error: Unable to enumerate the process modules.`

Any idea why? It's seems even though the code now adds almost all of them to the list, it's still flawed since it's still not adding several of them.

Regarding the 2 calls to `GetProcesses()`, I just stuck the `intProcessCount` in there while debugging. :)

Comment: @J.ScottElblein Win32Exception is too broad. Can you get the result code out of it and the stack trace?

Comment: According to the stack trace they all seem to be due to this line: `Dim ico As Icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(OneProcess.MainModule.FileName)`

Comment: That line still contains too many methods to give exact answer. Could you give me the names of the very first and very last methods in that stack trace? And one of the file names that cause the exception

Comment: It's ok, I think I found out why after finding this Q/A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23976825/how-can-i-add-to-listbox1-all-the-processes-names-and-also-each-process-icon-nea

Thanks for the help!