# Display Icon in WPF Image

Tags: c#, wpf, icons

I have a WPF application that needs to extract the icon off of an executable.

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203456/how-can-i-get-the-icon-from-the-executable-file-only-having-an-instance-of-its-p) that I can do this

```
Icon ico = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(theProcess.MainModule.FileName);
```

but when I try to set the source of a WPF Image I get

> "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Drawing.Icon' to 'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource'

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Icons get no love in the .NET framework.  You'll have to use Icon.Save() to save the icon you got into a MemoryStream.  Which allows you to use the IconBitmapDecoder constructor that takes a stream.

Answer (score 17):

`System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon` method can be use to convert a `System.Drawing.Icon` to wpf `BitmapSource`.

```
using(Icon ico = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(theProcess.MainModule.FileName))
{
    image.Source = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon(ico.Handle, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
}
```

Comment: it is simpler than suggestions with Bitmap. thanks for the answer, I will use it in my code !

Comment: For anyone getting blurry icons, see this stackoverflow answer about UseLayoutRounding="True" and/or RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode https://stackoverflow.com/a/2734431/848627

Answer (score 13):

I wanted to offer the solution I've come up with:

```
public static class IconExtensions
{
    [DllImport("gdi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);


    public static ImageSource ToImageSource(this Icon icon)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = icon.ToBitmap();
        IntPtr hBitmap = bitmap.GetHbitmap();

        ImageSource wpfBitmap = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
            hBitmap,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            Int32Rect.Empty,
            BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

        if (!DeleteObject(hBitmap))
        {
            throw new Win32Exception();
        }

        return wpfBitmap;
    }

}
```

I then have a IconToImageSourceConverter that simply calls the method above.

To make it easy for me to add icons as images I also added this:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type drawing:Icon}">
    <Image Source="{Binding Converter={converter:IconToImageSourceConverter}}" 
        MaxWidth="{Binding Width}" MaxHeight="{Binding Height}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

This way, if an icon is placed directly in XAML if will still be shown:

```
<x:Static MemberType="{x:Type drawing:SystemIcons}" Member="Asterisk"/>
```

Otherwise the converter can be used on location, like so:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Source={x:Static drawing:SystemIcons.Asterisk}, 
    Converter={converter:IconToImageSourceConverter}}"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem and in few steps we can get the image source:

```
ImageSource imageSource;

Icon icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(path);

using (Bitmap bmp = icon.ToBitmap())
{
   var stream = new MemoryStream();
   bmp.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
   imageSource = BitmapFrame.Create(stream);
}
```

We can use this image source to feed the property source in out XAML:

```
 <Image Source="{Binding Path=ImageSource, Mode=OneTime}" />
```

Comment: What about different icon resolutions (16x16, 48x48, etc.) ? Is there a way to select a resolution?

Answer (score 0):

I use this extension method to convert from Icon to ImageSource:

```
public static System.Windows.Media.ImageSource ToWpfImageSource(this System.Drawing.Icon icon)
{
   using (MemoryStream strm = new MemoryStream())
   {
        icon.Save(strm);
        return System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrame.Create(strm, System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapCreateOptions.None, System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);    
   }    
}
```

...

```
Icon icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(path);
ImageSouce imageWpf = icon.ToWpfImageSource();
```