# How to access to Application Icon (set from VS) from C# code in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, icons

Before asking the question, I looked for a possible similar or duplicate question, but I think I did not find it.

I will try to be synthetic and precise. I have correctly set the application icon through Visual Studio (Project > Settings > Application > Resources > Icon and Manifest > Icon). I would like to know how to access that icon from the C# code. How can I do it?

---

Going specifically, I would like to set that icon for the NotifyIcon object. Now I do not know if there is a standard procedure or not, but I would like to avoid loading two identical icons, one for the application and the other for the NotifyIcon object. I tried using `SystemIcons.Application` but it does not work.

---

The screenshot:

[image]

The code:

```
class MyHandsomeClass
{
        private NotifyIcon ni = new NotifyIcon();

        // ...

        private void NotifyError()
        {
            ni.Text = "Example";
            ni.BalloonTipText = "Un problema sconosciuto impedisce l'avvio del gioco, si prega di contattare gli amministratori";
            ni.BalloonTipTitle = "Impossibile eseguire il gioco";
            ni.Icon = SystemIcons.Application;     // This is not working
            ni.BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Error; // This is ok
            ni.Visible = true;
            ni.ShowBalloonTip(5000);
        }

        // ...

}
```

Comment: Almost duplicated [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873356/where-is-a-net-application-icon-stored)

Comment: I think they are two different questions with the same answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
ni.Icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(Application.ExecutablePath);
```

This finds the EXE and takes the icon from there