# Getting the icon representing a process with VB.net

Tags: vb.net, process, icons

I'm making a taskbar for something (I'll be creating similar to the windows taskbar).

I've managed to get all process objects that would be in the taskbar, how can I get the icon too?

Thanks if you can help!  I'm using VB.net so all .net answers are great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the technique in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/203490/507784) help?

The VB equivalent would be:

```
Dim ico As Icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(theProcess.MainModule.FileName)
```