# How to get a Window's Icon in C#

Tags: c#, .net, pointers, window, icons

How can I get a Window's icon from its Pointer or Process/Process Name? The Icon shown in the corner of the Window or on the Task-bar or in the ALT-Tab menu.

Comment: Find the window handle and send WM_GETICON

Comment: @DavidHeffernan This only works on Windows Mobile, not?

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/462270/get-file-icon-used-by-shell

Comment: @dor I don't see where WinMo comes into this.

Answer (score 2):

read about `Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon`:

> Returns an icon representation of an image that is contained in the
>   specified file.

```
private void ExtractAssociatedIconEx()
{
    Icon ico =
        Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(@"C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe");
    this.Icon = ico;

}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.icon.extractassociatedicon.aspx

This won't work on every process but it's a good start..

also take a look at those answers - [How can I get the icon from the executable file only having an instance of it's Process in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203456/how-can-i-get-the-icon-from-the-executable-file-only-having-an-instance-of-its)

Comment: @CarsenDanielYates your welcome, if you liked the answer please check the green mark and +1

Comment: This answer is wrong. The questions asks about the icon associated with a window rather than an executable.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Read the question again, How can I get a Window's icon from its Pointer or Process/Process Name?(PROCESS NAME)

Comment: Oh, Wait, sorry.  This won't work, I need to be able to make a full shell alteration, I have to get the icon from running processes.

Comment: The next bit says "The Icon shown in the corner of
the Window or on the Task-bar or in the ALT-Tab menu." and that's where WM_GETICON comes in.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks for the comments, it seems like good answer. why won't you post it? or edit my answer if you wish

Comment: I don't want to answer because question is contradictory. Processes don't have icons. Exe files do. Windows do. But not processes.

Answer (score 1):

Would [Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.icon.extractassociatedicon.aspx) work for you?