# How to get the text which is displayed in the menu bar or desktop when the window is minimized?

Tags: c#, c++, windows, sdl

I need to get the icon name of a process that used SDL-1.2.15 to display window.

This is SDL Description about SDL-window title and icon name :

> #include "SDL.h"
>
> ```
> void SDL_WM_SetCaption(const char *title, const char *icon);
> ```
>
> Sets the title-bar and icon name of the display window.
>
> title is a UTF-8 encoded null-terminated string which will serve as
>   the window title (the text at the top of the window). The function
>   does not change the string. You may free the string after the function
>   returns.
>
> icon is a UTF-8 encoded null-terminated string which will serve as the
>   iconified window title (the text which is displayed in the menu bar or
>   desktop when the window is minimized). As with title this string may
>   be freed after the function returns.

For example the ffplay used SDL and I can run it like this:

```
 Process p= new Process();
 p.StartInfo.FileName = "ffplay.exe";
 p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-i test.avi";
 p.Start();
```

Then I can get the title of window with `GetWindowText` API, But I can't get the icon name.

Please tell me how can I get the icon name. 
(Sorry for my English)

UPDATE :
I don't need to icon I need to the text which is displayed in the menu bar or desktop when the window is minimized.(that called icon name) Please read the SDL-Description.

Also I saw this : [Getting the icon associated with a running application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304109/getting-the-icon-associated-with-a-running-application)

But it does not work for me, Because `Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon` can not get icon name. So my question is not duplicate.

UPDATE :
I edited title of my question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting the icon associated with a running application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304109/getting-the-icon-associated-with-a-running-application)

Comment: If you want to get icon of **window**, then you can use winapi, something like `GetClassLong(hwnd, GCL_HICON)`. There is also associated with exe file icon (simply first icon in resources), for this see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9968661/1997232) answer.

Comment: I don't need to icon I need to the text which is displayed in the menu bar or desktop when the window is minimized.(that called icon name) Please read the SDL-Description .

Comment: @Mitra, have you tried [SDL_WM_GetCaption()](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_WM_GetCaption)? Also, for what it's worth, I believe the icon name is an X Window concept, it may not have an alternative on MS Windows.

Comment: @Frédéric ,I don't know what is "X Window " but I will try `SDL_WM_GetCaption()` . Thank you.