# How to mute or adjust volume on windows systems sounds?

Tags: c#, windows, system-sounds

I am working on an audio application, and it is vital that we can mute Windows systems sounds (warnings, notifications etc) at critical times

I can set the system volume and access a number of sound related things, but not the Windows systems sounds

I can access microphones, loudspeakers (waveOut) and the mixer. However while in older versions of Windows, the mixer would contain "Systems sounds", but later do not. Opening "Sound Settings" one will find "Systems sounds" under apps.
If I could get that list, and control it, then I can mute the system.

How do I access that ?

Comment: I recommend separating your two questions into two separate ones.

Comment: mixer API changed in Vista, wave/mixer functions are per app now.

Comment: @Anders, how do I access it?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/core-audio-apis-in-windows-vista but I don't remember if it gives you access to the system sounds in tge documented API

Comment: @Anders I guess I got some reading to do. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the link from Anders, I found the CoreAudio function, which lead me to IsSystemSoundsSession which then lead me to:

[How can i control the volume of a specific software in the windows Volume Mixer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33726863/how-can-i-control-the-volume-of-a-specific-software-in-the-windows-volume-mixer)

Here is a similar thing done, which can be easily used for muting the system sounds