# Select List View Items Using Dynamically Created Buttons - Code Limitations?

Tags: vb.net, button, dynamic, selection, listviewitem

[image]

After days of searching on the web and checking all SO similar questions here, I have a working version of the code I'm looking for! :-) But, it's very limited as I describe below! The reason is, I can't find a way to code for the way I want my program to work! The code below has taken me days and many attempts to get a working version! I'm using WIN10, Visual Studio 2019, VB.NET. Grateful to TEME64 for the example of creating buttons dynamically [dynamic buttons](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/197854/dynamically-adding-buttons). Does anyone know a more concise code to achieve the questions I have below? I would greatly appreciate your help!

**What I need:**

[image: dynamic buttons w/ icons]

The little program I'm trying to create **1.** Dynamically creates buttons from the total number of List View items (i.e. this is already working). **2.** It should then extract and apply program icons for each List View subitem to the dynamic buttons on a Flow Layout Panel (i.e. got this working for **one button at a time**, but I don't know how to **assign a different program icon to each button** from each of the paths in List View subitems)? **3.** Then, when you click each button, it should start a different external program (i.e. from paths in List View subitems - i.e. Process Start below). My List View columns are: NAME = Program Name; PATH = Program Exec file.

**Question 1:** How do I write more concise code? I tried changing the item's Index number dynamically using a Numeric Up Down control, but I couldn't get this working? I.e. only the first item remains selected and only the first program opens???
**Question 2:** How do I apply the program icons from each listview item to the dynamic button's background image independently of how many items there are in the List View or dynamic buttons which will be the same amount? The List View is sorted alphabetically!
**Question 3:** How do I handle user Cancel for external programs?

**What I have tried:**

**Creating Buttons Dynamically:**

The following code creates a button for each List View item. The buttons are contained on a Flow Layout Panel separately from the List View. The minus 1 is because the code was creating 4 buttons for 3 List View Items:

```
Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To ListView1.Items.Count.ToString - 1 '30 = number of buttons to create!!!
        NewButton(i)
    Next i
```

**Use Buttons to Select Different List View Items and Run Programs From Paths:**

The following code actually works! But, it is very limited in several ways: **1. Repetitive:** It's old school long hand. So, I need to repeat the code for each button/List View item! I don't want to limit the number of List View items or buttons created from them? A more objective code would be nice! **2. ButtonNumber:** Each button identifies itself by number (i.e. 0, 1, 2) but I don't know how to connect this to each List View item's index number (SelectedIndices?) in order to select each List View item using its corresponding button (i.e. button with program icon derived from path in List View)? **3. Exception:** The second program runs (i.e. Iobit Smart Defrag), but if I click Cancel on the Smart Defrag's startup dialog my code throws an exception which I don't know how to handle because it's an external program?

```
If ButtonNumber.ToString = 0 Then
        
        ListView1.SelectedItems.Clear()
        ListView1.SelectedIndices.Clear()
        ListView1.FocusedItem = ListView1.Items(0)
        ListView1.FocusedItem.Selected = True
        ListView1.FocusedItem.EnsureVisible()
        ListView1.Focus()

        Process.Start(ListView1.SelectedItems.Item(0).SubItems(1).Text.ToString())

    ElseIf ButtonNumber.ToString = 1 Then
        
        ListView1.SelectedItems.Clear()
        ListView1.SelectedIndices.Clear()
        ListView1.FocusedItem = ListView1.Items(1)
        ListView1.FocusedItem.Selected = True
        ListView1.FocusedItem.EnsureVisible()
        ListView1.Focus()

        'USER CANCEL THROWS EXCEPTION - HOW DO YOU HANDLE THIS???
        Process.Start(ListView1.SelectedItems.Item(0).SubItems(1).Text.ToString())

    ElseIf ButtonNumber.ToString = 2 Then
        
        ListView1.SelectedItems.Clear()
        ListView1.SelectedIndices.Clear()
        ListView1.FocusedItem = ListView1.Items(2)
        ListView1.FocusedItem.Selected = True
        ListView1.FocusedItem.EnsureVisible()
        ListView1.Focus()

        Process.Start(ListView1.SelectedItems.Item(0).SubItems(1).Text.ToString())

    End If
```

**Suggested Code Adaptations:**

I saved my original code to file and added the suggested code. I have made a few alterations to the code in an attempt to achieve my objective for the program (See new diagram above). However, although the alterations got me closer to what I need I currently can only get the results I want by selecting a LVW item and pressing the Get Selected Item button for each button to be added and their corresponding programs to run? Any ideas what I still need to do with the code to get it to: 1. Create a button for each LVW item; 2. Run a program from the selected item's subitem (i.e. exec Path)? 3. Pressing each button should select the corresponding LVW item and run the program?

**The Adapted Code:**

Changes: 1. Adapted myApps to load from LVW1 and added For Each loop; 2. Removed Button Text from create buttons because I only want the icon; 3. Added button size; 4. Moved LoadMyAppsList() and CreateButtons(myApps) from Form_Load to a button temporarily.

```
    Private Sub LoadMyAppsList()

'List Source = ListView1:
        For Each item As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items

            myApps = New List(Of ApplicationDetails)
            myApps.Add(New ApplicationDetails With
                       {.ApplicationName = ListView1.SelectedItems.Item(0).Text.ToString,
                       .ApplicationShortcut = ListView1.SelectedItems.Item(0).SubItems(1).Text.ToString(),
                       .ApplicationIcon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(ListView1.SelectedItems.Item(0).SubItems(1).Text.ToString())})
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub CreateButtons(myApps As List(Of ApplicationDetails))

        For Each appdet As ApplicationDetails In myApps

            Dim shortcutButton As Button = New Button With
                {.Image = appdet.ApplicationIcon.ToBitmap,
                .Tag = appdet.ApplicationShortcut}
            AddHandler shortcutButton.Click, AddressOf CommonButton_Click
            FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(shortcutButton)

            'Added - Button Size:
            shortcutButton.Width = 63
            shortcutButton.Height = 63

            MsgBox(appdet.ApplicationShortcut.ToString)

        Next

        'Removed:
        '.Text = appdet.ApplicationName,

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click

        ListView1.BeginUpdate()

        If ListView1.Items.Count > 0 AndAlso ListView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then

            LoadMyAppsList()
            CreateButtons(myApps)

        End If

        ListView1.EndUpdate()

    End Sub
```

**LVW Item Selection Using Buttons?**

After working with the code for quite a while I discovered a way to get the corresponding LVW items to select when their buttons are clicked. I'm sure there's probably a better way, but this works! What I need now is a way to open all the buttons in one go creating them from the LVW items. Currently, I need to manually select a LVW item, click the Get Selected Item button and a button is created. Then, repeat this for each button creation??? I've tried changing the LVW code lines from SelectedItems to Items, but this doesn't fix the problem??? The following code works for selecting LVW items:

```
Private Sub CommonButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    'Use variable to get exe path from button tag:
    Dim exePath As String = DirectCast(sender, Button).Tag.ToString

    'Find lvw item which contains same path as button tag:
    Dim item1 As ListViewItem = ListView1.FindItemWithText(exePath.ToString)
    
    'Select lvw item which corresponds to button: 
    ListView1.SelectedIndices.Clear()
    ListView1.FocusedItem = ListView1.Items(item1.Text.ToString)
    ListView1.FocusedItem.Selected = True
    ListView1.FocusedItem.EnsureVisible()
    ListView1.Focus()

    'Run program:
    Process.Start(exePath)

End Sub
```

**THE APP**

[image: My Favourite Apps List]

**THE CODE:**

I spent a lot of time debugging through the first code I found on Daniweb and also Andrew's code suggestions below to understand both of them. But, the code I have submitted below is a "no bells and whistles" version (i.e. minimal code for the app to work as proposed) that I managed to get working which is an adaptation of the code from Daniweb [dynamic buttons](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/197854/dynamically-adding-buttons):

```
'APP SETUP:
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    'LVW SETUP:
    Me.ListView1.View = View.Details
    Me.ListView1.HideSelection = False
    ListView1.FullRowSelect = True
    ListView1.GridLines = True
    ListView1.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending

    'SELECT FIRST LVW ITEM: 
    'COMMENT: Commented out lines which don't
    'affect first LVW item selection!!!
    'ListView1.SelectedIndices.Clear()
    ListView1.FocusedItem = ListView1.Items(0)
    ListView1.FocusedItem.Selected = True
    'ListView1.FocusedItem.EnsureVisible()
    ListView1.Select()
    'ListView1.Focus()

    'AUTORESIZE Name And Path COLUMNS
    Me.ListView1.AutoResizeColumn(0, ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent)
    Me.ListView1.AutoResizeColumn(1, ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent)

End Sub

'LOAD BUTTONS BUTTON:
Private Sub Button8_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button8.Click

    'CLEAR BUTTONS TO PREVENT DUPLICATES:
    FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear()

    'GET LVW ITEM'S TEXT:
    Dim username As String
    Dim session As String
    Dim output As String

    For Each item As ListViewItem In Me.ListView1.Items

        username = item.Text
        session = item.SubItems.Item(1).Text
        output = session 'username + " : " + session

        'OUTPUT RESULTS TO CONSOLE:
        Console.WriteLine(output)

        'EXTRACT PROGRAM EXE FILES FROM LVW SUBITEM PATHS:
        Dim ico As Icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(output)

        'CREATE AND ADD NEW BUTTONS:
        Dim btn As New Button
        FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(btn)
        btn.BackgroundImage = ico.ToBitmap
        btn.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch
        btn.Size = New Size(63, 63)

        'ADD PATHS FROM LVW SUBITEMS TO EACH BUTTON TAG:
        btn.Tag = output

        'HANDLE DYNAMIC BUTTON'S CLICK (i.e. Links to dynamic buttons click event)
        AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf onButtonClick

    Next

End Sub

'DYNAMIC BUTTONS CLICK - RUN PROGRAMS FROM BUTTONS:
Private Sub onButtonClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    'UPDATE LVW:
    ListView1.BeginUpdate()

    'CHECK SENDING BUTTON'S TAG:
    If CType(sender, Button).Tag IsNot Nothing Then

        'FIND LVW SUBITEM PATH WHICH CORRESPONDS TO PATH IN BUTTON TAG:
        Dim item1 As ListViewItem = ListView1.FindItemWithText(CType(sender, Button).Tag.ToString)

        'CHECK PATHS CORRESPOND:
        If (item1 IsNot Nothing) Then

            With ListView1

                'BUTTON CLICK SELECTS CORRESPONDING LVW ITEM: 
                .SelectedIndices.Clear()
                .FocusedItem = item1
                .FocusedItem.Selected = True
                .FocusedItem.EnsureVisible()
                .Focus()

            End With

            'RUN CORRESPONDING PROGRAM - PTL!!!
            Process.Start(ListView1.SelectedItems.Item(0).SubItems(1).Text.ToString)

            'THIS ALSO RUNS EACH PROGRAM CORRESPONDING WITH BUTTONS-PTL!!!
            'Process.Start(CType(sender, Button).Tag.ToString)

        Else

            'USER NOTIFICATION:
            MessageBox.Show("Item not found!")

        End If

    End If

    'END UPDATE LVW:
    ListView1.EndUpdate()

End Sub
```

**Andrew Mortimer's Code:**

I have tried the new code, but after renaming according to the naming convention I have used, adding the path to the CSV file, etc., I get the following exception: System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string "ASC;C:\Program Files (x86)\IObit" to type 'Integer' is not valid.' on the following code block:

```
myApps.Add(New ApplicationDetails With
                   {.ID = values(0),
                   .ApplicationName = values(1),
                   .ApplicationShortcut = values(2),
                   .ApplicationIcon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(values(2))
                   })
```

Comment: Put the path to the executable into the button's tag property, and then use the tag on button click.

Comment: Try this for the icon: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203456/how-can-i-get-the-icon-from-the-executable-file-only-having-an-instance-of-its

Comment: Hey Andrew, I'm just wondering if your code already adds the exec to button's tag in the Create Buttons sub? i.e. .Tag = appdet.ApplicationShortcut?

Comment: I'm a little unclear. Do you want the button click to select the listviewitem and execute the listview item's associated exe?

Comment: Sorry about that! Yes, I want a button to be created for each ListViewItem and when I click on a button it should select the LVW item to indicate which item it is working with, then it should get the path from the subitem and run the associated program's exec file. I guess it's kind of like program shortcuts on the desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this will get you close to what you need.
It is using a custom class to store your application details.
It uses a common button click event handler to handle all the click events.

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class ButtonsForm

    Private myApps As List(Of ApplicationDetails)
    Private maxAppId As Integer

    Private Class ApplicationDetails

        Public Property ID As Integer
        Public Property ApplicationName As String
        Public Property ApplicationShortcut As String
        Public Property ApplicationIcon As Icon

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Comma delim property to use when writing out app file
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <returns></returns>
        Public ReadOnly Property WriteLine As String
            Get
                Return String.Join(",", ID, ApplicationName, ApplicationShortcut)
            End Get
        End Property

    End Class

    Private Sub CommonButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

        'get the application id
        Dim searchID As Integer = DirectCast(sender, Button).Tag

        'find it in the listview
        For Each lv As ListViewItem In AppListView.Items
            If lv.Tag = searchID Then
                lv.Selected = True
                LaunchApplication(lv.SubItems(1).Text)
            End If
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub LaunchApplication(applicationPath As String)

        Process.Start(applicationPath)

    End Sub

    Private Sub LoadMyAppsListFromCSV()

        Dim csvFilePath As String = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "MyApps.csv")

        'initialise app list
        myApps = New List(Of ApplicationDetails)

        Dim lines() As String = File.ReadAllLines(csvFilePath)

        For Each line In lines
            Dim values() As String = line.Split(Convert.ToChar(","))
            myApps.Add(New ApplicationDetails With
                       {.ID = values(0),
                       .ApplicationName = values(1),
                       .ApplicationShortcut = values(2),
                       .ApplicationIcon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(values(2))
                       })
        Next

        'get the max app id to be used if another application is added
        maxAppId = myApps.Max(Function(x) x.ID)

    End Sub

    Private Sub CreateButtons(myApps As List(Of ApplicationDetails))

        'clear the controls
        ButtonsFLP.Controls.Clear()

        'add back
        For Each appdet As ApplicationDetails In myApps

            Dim shortcutButton As Button = New Button With
                {.Text = appdet.ApplicationName,
                .Image = appdet.ApplicationIcon.ToBitmap,
                .Tag = appdet.ID}
            AddHandler shortcutButton.Click, AddressOf CommonButton_Click
            ButtonsFLP.Controls.Add(shortcutButton)

        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub InitFormButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles InitFormButton.Click

        InitForm()

    End Sub

    Private Sub InitForm()

        LoadMyAppsListFromCSV()
        CreateButtons(myApps)
        CreateListView(myApps)

    End Sub

    Private Sub CreateListView(myApps As List(Of ApplicationDetails))

        AppListView.Items.Clear()

        For Each appdet As ApplicationDetails In myApps

            Dim lvitem As ListViewItem = AppListView.Items.Add(appdet.ApplicationName)
            lvitem.SubItems.Add(appdet.ApplicationShortcut)
            lvitem.Tag = appdet.ID

        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub AddAppButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AddAppButton.Click

        Try
            Dim myNewApp As ApplicationDetails = New ApplicationDetails() With
                    {.ApplicationName = ApplicationNameTextBox.Text,
                    .ApplicationShortcut = ApplicationPathTextBox.Text
            }
            If ValidForAdd(myNewApp) Then
                AddApplication(myNewApp)
                InitForm()
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(String.Concat("An error occurred: ", ex.Message))
        End Try

    End Sub

    Private Sub AddApplication(myNewApp As ApplicationDetails)

        'get the next id
        myNewApp.ID = maxAppId + 1
        'add to the collection
        myApps.Add(myNewApp)
        'rewrite the collection
        WriteAppCollectionToCsv(myApps)

    End Sub

    Private Sub WriteAppCollectionToCsv(myApps As List(Of ApplicationDetails))

        Dim csvFilePath As String = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "MyApps.csv")
        Dim backupFile As String = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, String.Format("MyApps_{0}.csv", Guid.NewGuid.ToString()))
        'backup the current file just in case..
        File.Move(csvFilePath, backupFile)
        'write the new file
        Using sw As New StreamWriter(csvFilePath)
            For Each item As ApplicationDetails In myApps
                sw.WriteLine(item.WriteLine)
            Next
        End Using

    End Sub

    Private Function ValidForAdd(myNewApp As ApplicationDetails) As Boolean

        If myNewApp.ApplicationName.Trim.Length = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter an application name", Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
            ApplicationNameTextBox.Focus()
            Return False
        End If

        If myNewApp.ApplicationShortcut.Trim.Length = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter an application path", Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
            ApplicationPathTextBox.Focus()
            Return False
        End If

        Dim appExists As Boolean = myApps.Any(Function(x) x.ApplicationName = myNewApp.ApplicationName And x.ApplicationShortcut = myNewApp.ApplicationShortcut)
        If appExists Then
            MessageBox.Show("You've added this already", Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
            ApplicationNameTextBox.Focus()
            ApplicationNameTextBox.SelectAll()
            Return False
        End If

        Return True

    End Function

    Private Sub RemoveAppButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RemoveAppButton.Click

        Try
            If AppListView.SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Please select an application to remove", Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
                Return
            End If

            If DeleteSelectedApp() Then
                InitForm()
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(String.Concat("An error occurred: ", ex.Message))
        End Try

    End Sub

    Private Function DeleteSelectedApp() As Boolean

        'get the id
        Dim delId As Integer = DirectCast(AppListView.SelectedItems(0).Tag, Integer)

        Dim appItemToRemove As ApplicationDetails = myApps.Where(Function(x) x.ID = delId).First
        myApps.Remove(appItemToRemove)
        WriteAppCollectionToCsv(myApps)

        Return True

    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Hey Andrew, thanks for that great code! That has given me some real pointers! I have just added a new diagram to better explain what I'm trying to do. Also, I posted the adaptations I made to your code in an attempt to reach my objective. However, I'm still running into a couple of problems as I mentioned above. I will try the other suggestion you gave above. If you have any more suggestions on the new diagram and comments I just made I would really appreciate it! Thanks! :-)

Comment: Updated with the ability to find and select the list view item

Comment: Thank you Andrew! Removed old code, added new code. It works, but in LoadMyAppsList() tried unsuccessfully to adapt the code. LVW items are user added. Hard coding paths or repeating code for each program isn't an option? I won't know the total number of items in ListView? To be flexible, I need to derive the number of buttons and paths directly from the LVW? I have already tested icon extraction and exec paths directly from LVW which works. But, try as I might, looping though all LVW items doesn't work to create buttons with icons for each item which work as shortcuts to run exec files?

Comment: My code has the hard coded collection just for test purposes. Your input can be whatever you want it to be. What is the sequence of events? Do you load the already added LVW items from a text file when the form starts, and then allow users to add manually after that?

Comment: Hi Andrew. Thanks once again! I tried replacing the hard-coding with a loop as I show above. I don't know how to get it to work? I can get all data in a message box when debugging. But, the loop only produces one button not 3 as per my test data? Yes, I have an existing list stored in a CSV file which I load in Form_Load. The idea is for the user to also be able to add items to the list, i.e. 1. Load from CSV to LVW; 2. Create buttons with icons from total number of LVW items; 3. Use button click to select LVW item and run program from subitem path: 4. User adds items to LVW, saves LVW to CSV.

Comment: You have this ' myApps = New List(Of ApplicationDetails)' inside your 'For Each item As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items' loop so it keeps reinitialising it. Move it outside the for loop and it should have all the items in it.

Comment: Code updated with add/remove/validation.

Comment: Hi Andrew. Thanks once again! I tried your suggestion, but ended up with a number of buttons created with the same icon for the same app (i.e. the first item in the LVW)? I have also been working on the other code I started with and got it working in the way I want it to. I have posted above the minimal code for the app to work with no bells or whistles.

Comment: I'm still interested in your code because it has interesting features! I really want to get it working! Then, there will be more code options! I spent a huge amount of time looking for a way to select LVW items using dynamic buttons. But, the code I posted above really does point the buttons to the LVW item, selects the item and then the code gets the exec path from the selected subitem and runs the program! I couldn't believe it when the code actually started working! :-)

Comment: "Dim btn As New Button 'NB: CAN'T MAKE THIS GLOBAL BECAUSE IT STOPS CREATING ALL THE BUTTONS AND ONLY CREATES A SINGLE BUTTON???" <- hard to comment on that without seeing the code. There isn't much value to making the button global. It should be created where you have it right now. That's the correct scope I think.

Comment: Hi Andrew. Thanks for alerting me to that comment. I forgot to remove it. I was previously thinking of moving the variable to the Declarations area so I could use it globally throughout the code. But, in the end, it wasn't necessary!

Comment: No problem. Mark this as an answer if you're happy enough with it. :)

Comment: Hi Andrew. Your code is looking great! But, I added a post above to detail an exception I'm getting under Andrew Mortimer's code. I couldn't get the code working yet so I'm not sure if your error handling answers my question about user cancelling external app? Also, not sure if I understand what maxappid is unless that just refers to ID or ID number? I'm wondering if you've coded for numbered rows and whether or not that's why an exception is thrown? My LVW just has two columns, NAME and PATH. So, the code finds a text string and throws an exception? Not sure?

Comment: I added an ID so that you can have multiple apps, with the same name, different shortcuts. As you don't have an ID in position 0 in your file, it'll throw the error you're seeing above.